# OpenSSH client not connecting after deleting id_rsa

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, openssl

So I stupidly overwrote my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files earlier, and I just decied to rm -rf the whole .ssh folder because it was all corrupted/broken after tinkering with it. Ever since that when I try to connect to ssh servers my client just hangs. Here is the output for -v

```
huoy@huoy:~$ ssh -v xxxx@xxxxx.xx -p xx
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxx@xxxxx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port xx.
```

Anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Thanks

Edit: I just realised I can connect to other servers via ssh. I think it's something to do with the server, though I'm not sure what. Shouldn't it just reject me if I don't have the right keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have removed your private keys.

> The private key is kept on the computer you log in from,
>   while the public key is stored on the .ssh/authorized_keys
>   file on all the computers you want to log in to.

<sub>[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)</sub>

If you have no backup, you have to generate a new key pair and copy the public key to the server again.

Comment: I did try that before, and it didn't actually work. But I tried to add the public key via my host's control panel, which didn't solve the issue. Obviously I can't login to ssh to add the key to the authorized_keys manually. I've contacted my host so if it ends up being something useful I'll post back with my results.

Comment: Okay you were actually right. My host's backend key uploader was malfunctioning so I had to ssh from another one of my servers and add my new key to the authorized_keys file.

Comment: That's fine . Do you have an upvote for me? ;)

Comment: Yes, I do...  :p